# "best practice" way to get a finished document from template

Tags: powershell

I have a template like this one

```
$template = @"
Template name
field: #value#
field: #value#
field: #value#
end
"@
```

and hash table

```
$hash = @{
    field1 = value1
    field2 = value2
    field3 = value3
}
```

could you please explain to me, what is the "best practice" way to get a finished document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide for yourself what is *"best practice"*, but I would change the template so it has placeholders instead of `#value#` like this:

```
Template name
field: {0}
field: {1}
field: {2}
end
"@
```

Now you can do

```
$document = $template -f ($hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { $_.Value })
```

or

```
$document = $template -f ($hash.Keys | ForEach-Object { $hash[$_] })
```

To produce

```
Template name
field: value2
field: value3
field: value1
end
```

Since a normal Hashtable is unordered, the values are randomly set to the different fields in the template.
If that is unwanted, make the Hashtable `Ordered` like this

```
$hash = [ordered]@{
    field1 = 'value1'
    field2 = 'value2'
    field3 = 'value3'
}
```

so the above would output

```
Template name
field: value1
field: value2
field: value3
end
```